# use case of process_spider_input in spidermiddleware

Tags: scrapy

Does anyone know the difference between  `process_spider_input(response, spider)` in **spidermiddleware** and  `process_response(request, response, spider)` in  **Downloadermiddleware**.
And how to choose one over another, because I see they do quite the same work, they handle response.

Answer (score 0):

According to the source, they do have difference

- return value

  - `spider_mw.process_spider_input()` returns `None`, you can check or modify the `Response`. Basically it supposes the response has been accepted and you can't refuse it.
  - `downloader_mw.process_response()` returns `Response` or `Request`. You can refuse the response from download handler and generate a new request. (e.g. the `RetryMiddleware`）